# Turing Machine for Check Validity of Unary Multiplication (A=B*C)

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, automata, computer-vision, multiplication

I have a lot of difficulty with the turing machines. I understand the theory well, but I need help with a lab exercise...

> Design a **SINGLE TAPE Turing Machine** that accepts the language $a =
> > b \times c$ (or $1^{^{mn}}= 1^{^{m}} \times 1^{^{n}} )$, this means
> that this language only accepts **unary** multiplications.
>
> Some examples are :
>
> - 1111=11x11 is accepted
> - 1=1x1 is accepted
> - 111111=11x111 is accepted
> - 11x1 is not accepted
> - 11111=1111x11 is not accepted

The order with the result in front is imperative. The input is accepted only if the calculation is correct *(we dont need to check the pattern)*.

I search help for drawing this Turing machine…

Thanks you for your help...

Comment: Have you experimented with some online Turing machine simulator such as [this one](http://morphett.info/turing/)?

Comment: Yes @JohnL. but I need help to draw this machine...

Comment: Suppose $m$ is fixed to be $1$. Can you design that machine?